# c++ invalid conversion from int* to int

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<class T>
T f(T x, T y)
{
    return x+y;
}
int f(int x, int y)
{
    return x-y;
}
int main()
{
    int *a=new int(3), b(23);
    cout<<f(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'
initializing argument 1 of 'int f(int, int)' . What does it mean ?

Thanks

Comment: `a` is a `int*` but the function expects a `int`.

Comment: The variables `a` and `b` have different and non-compatible types.

Comment: What do you expect the type of `a` to be, and what do you expect for `b`?

Comment: Why are you even using a pointer?

Comment: did you code in Java before ? you don't have to create pointers to single elements. Unless you want to create arrays with `[]` ?

Comment: @NathanOliver the OP may be learning C++ and trying out an exercise.

Comment: And learning C++ just by trying exercises is, as I will not get tired to repeat, a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dereference `a` in your call to `f`. This is because `a` is a *pointer to* an `int`, while `b` is a bare `int`. Dereferencing a pointer to an `int` returns an `int`. This results in the function `f` being called with two ints.

```
cout<<f(*a,b);
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The template function can take pointers (though it may result in a compilation error to add two pointers). But, here the two parameters of the template function are of the same type, and when arguments of two different types (`int *` and `int`) are provided, template deduction fails.

Comment: @fefe: the template function can't take pointers, because you can't add pointers.

Comment: As OP sadly [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087916/c-random-numbers-when-returning-pointer-from-function), it can take a pointer and an `int` though.

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us what exectly you want to achieve ??

You need to use * operator to get value from 'a' pointer.

```
f(*a,b) //this invocation should work.
```

regardless of the fact that this code compiles without errors, it is ugly

Answer (score 1):

```
int f(int x, int y)
{
    return x-y;
}
```

In your above function, first parameter expects an integer argument, and not an address pointing to an integer value. So what you need to make sure is that the data types of your FUNCTION PARAMETERS must match the data types of your FUNCTION ARGUMENTS. Otherwise, such compilation errors will always pop up at compilation time.

So in your case, there are following solutions to this problem:

1. change your function parameter int x to int* x Or
2. change your f(a,b) to f(*a,b) so that value of a is sent not address Or
3. declare a as a simple integer like you did for b. Then while calling f function, send address of variable a. Make sure for this option, function parameter int x should be changed to int* x