# c++ random numbers when returning pointer from function

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following code in C++ . Everytime I run it ,it has a different output. Why does this happen ? Is it somehow related to memory leak ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <class T, class U>
T f(T x, U y)
{
    return x+y;
}
int f(int x, int y)
{
    return x-y;
}
int main()
{
    int *a=new int(4), b(16);
    cout<<*f(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is more related to you trying to learn C++ by trial and error. That will not work. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl who says f return an int? As a is int* which is injected in T?

Comment: @lordjohncena I overlooked the template bit - hence why I deleted my comment when I realized.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. What did you actually expect to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are passing a pointer and a normal `int` to `f`, because

```
int *a=new int(4), b(16);
```

works like

```
int *a=new int(4);
int b(16);
```

Thus, in `f`, you have `T == int*` and `U == int`, then you add the `int` to the pointer and return the resulting pointer. As it does not point to memory you own and initialized, dereferencing it is UB and may yield garbage or crash or do whatever it likes.

As I already said in the comments, you should not try to learn C++ by trial and error, that really will not work, believe me. Learn it systematically from a good book instead. You will see that there is no need to use pointers for this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for your advice. I tried this method because I wanted to try coding my own small programs and maybe understand better c++ .

Comment: @locket23 You're welcome. But I really can't stress enough how important a good learning resource is for that. C++ is a quite powerful tool, but it also is a maze of pitfalls and bad practice that will bite you again and again if you are not careful.